# Using Roadkill wiki on authenticated website for help system

Tags: roadkill-wiki

Posted this on google groups for Roadkill wiki, but there seems to be not much activity. Stackoverflow was mentioned, but there's only 2 posts per year...  Bitbucket account is closed... Seems wrong to add an issue in github to just ask questions... https://github.com/roadkillwiki/roadkill/issues

I want to create a help wiki for a password protected website (asp.net, c#, iis...). This website is using Form Authentication. Only users logged onto the site will be able to see the help pages. They will be able to READ the pages, not add or edit or register new users or anything like that.

1) admin access
There will be 1 (or 2 or 3) admin users who can add/edit/delete pages. They can use a special URL to get to the admin pages if required.
- They use their own credentials from the real website somehow mapped as admin in Roadkill, or
- have special Roadkil user+pwd, defined in Roadkill rather than the real website.

2) For the read only requirement, I see it's work in progress for v3.
https://github.com/roadkillwiki/roadkill#viewer-role
http://roadkillwiki.userecho.com/topics/27-viewer-role/
I know it says "no ETA", but are we talking 1 month, 6 months, 1 year? I might have to do my own as I need this within a month or two!

3) For authentication of my readonly users... I thought I would have to write my own "User Manager", using the technique described here:
http://www.roadkillwiki.net/wiki/12/users-and-permissions
But then I thought... If I just install Roadkill in a protected folder in the root of my website, doesn't this give me Form Authentication for free? I don't care who the users are, all pages will be readonly for them... a kind of anonymous access... but I saw anonymous access doesn't exist.
Then I saw this question:
http://roadkillwiki.userecho.com/topics/10-port-it-to-aspnet-identity/
and the answer is no, "asp.net identity doesn't support groups". But it supports roles, so you could have admins, editors (and viewers), am I missing something?

Any tips regarding the 3 points above? It's borderline off topic by stackoverflow standards, I know. So let's make it a real question: how to configure Roadkill in a Form authenticated asp.net website so that all users have readonly access, to create a series of help pages?

There aren't that many .net wikis out there! It's all php!

Comment: Forgot to mention, there's also a codeplex site with issues there http://roadkill.codeplex.com/ some blog here http://www.anotherchris.net/tags.html#roadkill-wiki and other forum here: http://roadkillwiki.userecho.com/lists/1-general/  Difficult to know which to use!